# Is there any problem if I send a push with token data using a loop (for) regardless of the number of people?

Tags: node.js, firebase, function, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase lacks the search function, so I use Algolia.

I'm trying to send pushes only to specific people using Algolia, but is it okay if I send a push to the searched people regardless of the number of people?
The server is being used as a fire base function.

The most interesting part is "Is there any problem if I send a push with token data using a loop (for) regardless of the number of people?"

Oh, of course, the searched information includes user-specific token information

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the method of sending to [multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?hl=ko#send-messages-to-multiple-devices), it took a method of sending 500 people by repeating each other.

I haven't tested it with many users yet, but looping 20 times for 2 people succeeded.

I hope that less than 10,000 people can do it.